# I can't download from https on MonoDroid - am I missing something obvious?

Tags: https, xamarin.android

Here's the code I'm running:

```
        var wc = new WebClient ();
        var test1 = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
        var test2 = wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.com");
```

`test1` gives me some text.

`test2` never gets initialised because of an exception with trace starting:

> {System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write:
>   EndWrite failure): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: EndWrite
>   failure ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket has been
>   shut down   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndSend (IAsyncResult result)
>   [0x0002d] in
>   /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1989
>   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (IAsyncResult ar)
>   [0x0002f] in
>   /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:358
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (IAsyncResult ar) [0x0003d]
>   in
>   /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:360
>   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndSendRecord
>   (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in
>   /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:721
>   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (ContentType
>   contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x0000b] in
>   /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:729

I'm running MonoDevelop.MonoDroid - 2.6.0.0 - with a download from MonoDroid a couple of days ago - "Mono for Android: 1.2.24817.105690530 (Evaluation)"

Is this just a bug - or is there some other step I need for MonoDroid?

Comment: i have also a problem with SSL in MonoDroid and i think that there is some core bugs. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994662/error-when-sending-email-with-system-net-mail-smtpclient

Comment: thanks - I'll try tweeting some of them...

Comment: I've logged on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2031 - is this just a bug? Still open to the idea that I'm missing something in the android permissions (or similar)

Comment: INTERNET permission is checked?

Comment: @sound - Yes - the app has permission to successfully make the HTTP call - that works fine - but is there some other permission for HTTPs (I've not heard of it before, but maybe there's something...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this has been confirmed as a bug in the 1.2 release - so I'm closing this question!